# Is there a way to get method references from views in MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I would like to see all references of a given method. I mean references in C# sources and views (.aspx, .ascx, .cshtml). Is there a way to do that? A VS2012 setting or a plugin?

Answer (score 3):

If you changed a method and you use it in your Views and don't know which one, you can always change the `MvcBuildViews` attribute in `.csproj`.

`<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

Resharper is an excellent tool that allows you to find all usages (this includes Views) in your solution.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

There are also some alternatives to resharper:

CodeRush: http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Try.xml

JustCode: http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/09-11-18/code-just-code-justcode.aspx

VisualAssistX: http://www.wholetomato.com/

The only one free is VSCommands:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/ , but i don't know for sure if it has that functionality.

There is also a customer feedback here: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3090767-make-find-all-references-search-in-mvc-views, in case you want to track it's status.

Comment: I have `<MvcBuildViews>` set to true already. Is there a free for commercial use equivalent of the plugin with this functionality?